# I'm trying to design a histogram kinda function

Tags: c#, color-scheme, histogram, similarity

I have a logo and I would like to retrieve the "most used colors", but filter similar colors.

My idea is like the Kuler from Adobe, where you get 3-5 colors that will look nice together. They are often quite a bit apart in the "colorwheel".

So, I receive a image and I would like to see if there is some kinda way to figure out what primary colors it have and then after this result try to figure out what colors would look "Kuler" combined with it.

Question:

How do I make a historygram function that will "group similar colors" ??? To build the histogram I guess I would just make an array of "found colors" and then ++ each time found while scanning the image pixel by pixel.

But instead of RGB(xx,yy,zz) in 256 tones, I think this should be roughly "lowered" to eg. 16 values or perhaps less?

Has anyone done similar or do you have any ideas of how to get started?

I would love to see somekinda example in C# as thats my preferede language for this task.

Comment: Would it be possible to use HTML colour codes and get a range of values that are a similar colour? Maybe give it a base colour, and then change the HEX values (which I'm pretty sure are grouped RRGGBB) by a bit either way if possible. Just an idea, I'm not entirely sure of the best way to go about it.

Comment: The RGB color space consists of *far* more than 256 individual colors. And doing this in 256 or 16 colors is going to produce *terrible* results. I recommend researching color theory a little more extensively before undertaking a project like this.

Comment: I am aware of 24-bit colors (hench xx,yy,zz in 256 tones). So thats 256*256*256 colors or approx 16,7 mill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools such as Kuler use color models to determine what colors are 'similar', what the 'illumination' of a color is, how 'bright' a color is or what its counter color is.

So you might want to read about [color models on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory)

Secondly see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106190/algorithm-challenge-generate-color-scheme-from-an-image)

Comment: since no-one else seems to have a good answer, I am marking yours. Thanks for the links.