# Look for color schema selection algorithms

Tags: algorithm, colors

When developing sites (or GUI) there are problem on selecting color schema (like making header - red, footer - blue, sidebar - yellow, text - black, zebra - white/green).

There are color schema exchange sites, freeware tools and sites. Like http://colorschemedesigner.com/

But search on Github/SourceForge/FreeCode didn't give any OpenSource tools to study used algorithms and techniques for picking color schema.

My goal to build such tools (I think simply in JS/HTML5) but I don't understand how to  select color combination so it look *acceptable* for people.

PS. I don't ask this question at http://ux.stackexchange.com as its rules state that algorithms are offtopic at UX.

**UPDATE**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory
- [Algorithm to randomly generate an aesthetically-pleasing color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044/algorithm-to-randomly-generate-an-aesthetically-pleasing-color-palette)
- [Algorithm challenge: Generate color scheme from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106190/algorithm-challenge-generate-color-scheme-from-an-image)

Comment: Probably it's not UX or programming question but more a psychology question, since we need to select appropriate set of colors, or color that people like to see.

Comment: @Mysterion In any case job must be done (project page, personal blog, home page). I do many home pet projects and any acceptable color schema picker would be fine (not like black/cyan/green home page and blogs of some nerds, and not the best, for this you hire professionals and pay money).

Comment: Yeah, I understand you. It's actually very interesting problem, that's why i bookmark it :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [ux.se] or psychology (I realize that this is asking for an algorithm, but a first step is to actually determine some basic rules to base this algorithm on, which is off topic, at least in my opinion).

Comment: @Dukeling Which StackExch site suitable for this question? UX for example also forbid this question according to FAQ... Question mostly about specific domain, not about bytes and frameworks...